# Twitter Banner Picture API

Tags: php, twitter

i am trying to retrive the users Banner Image with the twitter API, but the URL is blank. Below is my code.

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key,$consumer_secret,$OAUTH_TOKEN,$OAUTH_SECRET);

$ProfileBanner = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/profile_banner.json?screen_name='.$screen_name);

$banner= $ProfileBanner->url;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [`users/profile_banner` API endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/profile_banner) returns a structure containing multiple versions of the banner image at different resolutions. It's not just a single URL; read the documentation for details.

Also, the API endpoint will return a 404 if the user hasn't uploaded a profile banner.